# My docker-compose file is not working when I try to connect mysql with Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

I am running into a little issue with connecting my node.js docker container to my MySQL docker container.

**db.config.js** file:

```
module.exports = {
HOST: process.env.DATABASE_HOST || '127.0.0.1',
PORT: 6603,
USER: "root",
PASSWORD: "root",
DB: "menu"};
```

**docker-compose.yml** file:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
    node-app:
        build: .
        environment:
            - DATABASE_HOST=db
        depends_on:
            - db
        links:
            - db
        ports:
            - 3001:3000
        container_name: api
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: 'menu'
        ports:
            - 6603:3306
        container_name: mysqldb
```

My **Dockerfile** for the Node.js app:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD npm start
EXPOSE 3000
```

When I run the **docker-compose up** command, the following error returns:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.28.0.2:3306
```

Any help to resolve this would be very appreciated.

Comment: Change port on `module.exports` as 3306 according to your docker-compose. In your compose file you have 6603:3306 it's  _Map my host port 6603 to container port 3306_; HOST:CONTAINER

Comment: I managed to figure it out. The MySQL container was taking longer to run than the node container, so I added a delay to the database connection and it works now. Thanks for your response though.